# Handlebars helper not getting value of variable

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm Trying to create a custom "if_eq" helper for a Handlebars / Ember application.  The helper is called with the following syntax: {{#if_eq item.name 'bob'}}, but is receiving 2 string values to compare (literally 'item.name' and 'bob'), instead of the value of "item.name" in the context it was called.  Wondering what I might be doing wrong.  Thanks!

Relevant code snippets are listed below and also created a jsbin to illustrate the problem [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sebihidede/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

**Helper Code**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    console.log( "Comparing ", a, b);
    if(a == b)
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

**Template code**

```
<ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
        {{#if_eq item.name 'bob'}}
            <li>We have a bob here!</option>
        {{else}}
            <li>A non-bob</li>
        {{/if_eq}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars helpers don't play nice with bound properties.

Generally you'll want to avoid such logic in your templates. Specifically, either create a method on your controller, or the object itself, so that you say something like: `if item.isBob`.

E.g. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fudadugemu/2/edit?html,js,output

Or you could use a component and have a little fun with it, something like this:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/buyeqenumo/2/edit

(try changing the bob input)

Comment: Hey Kori, thanks for the reply.  Disappointed to hear that helpers don't work with bound properties ... pretty much makes them useless.  Is it possible to work with unbound properties?  Think I was somewhat mislead by the handlebar helper libraries out there, such as: https://github.com/danharper/Handlebars-Helpers, but they suffer from the same issue it seems

Comment: When I say "don't play nice," I mean you can do it, it just requires jumping through hoops. If you really have your heart set on doing it though: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#toc_example-with-multiple-bound-properties